# Extend OWL class and check for inconsistencies

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, pellet

I want to extend the `Hand` class defined in SOMA in my own Ontology defined with namespace `http://example.org/test.owl`

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.ease-crc.org/ont/SOMA.owl#Hand">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.ease-crc.org/ont/SOMA.owl#PrehensileEffector"/>
    <rdfs:comment>A prehensile effector including palm, fingers, and thumb.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://www.ease-crc.org/ont/SOMA-OBJ.owl"/>
</owl:Class>
```

which would look something like

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.ease-crc.org/ont/SOMA.owl#Hand">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#isRegionFor"/>
            <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minCardinality>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://example.org/test.owl#Span"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</rdf:Description>
```

Firstly, does this correctly define that every instance of `Hand` has to have at least one association with `Span` through `isRegionFor` property?

Now to test it, I created an instance of Hand (with SOMA namespace) without any association to Span and ran the Pellet reasoner, but the reasoner did not complain. Is this something to do with namespace of Hand (because I have extended it in an Ontology with new namespace) or some configuration of Pellet?

Comment: Stating `Hand SubClassOf isRegionFor min 1 Span` is **not** as constraint in OWL, but used for inference. The whole paradigm in standard OWL inference is *deductive reasoning*. Moreover, the Open World Assumption holds in OWL, thus, a reasoner can't know just be absence of such a fact that there no no fact at all somewhere in the world. Thus, no inconsistency will hold here.

Comment: What tool did you use to create the extension with? I.e., if I express the same using Protege, the RDF that is rendered has the restrictions between 2 different `<owl:Restriction>`, not a single one as you have.

Answer (score 1):

OWL follows the [open-world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption) ‒ in order to report inconsistency, it is not enough that the graph is *missing* facts ‒ you have to disprove them explicitly; in other words, removing triples can never create a contradiction. Your ontology tells the reasoner that a `Hand` is in a relation with at least one `Span`, and there is no triple that would contradict that.

There are no satisfactory ways to do this with OWL ‒ you could remove the `rdfs:subClassOf` in your ontology and then check with the reasoner that every member of `Hand` is also a member of your `owl:Restriction`. However, that does not require a "direct" proof, since you could assert this membership explicitly, i.e. a "malicious" graph could imply that a particular `Hand` is linked to some `Span`, but it has no obligation to identify that particular individual explicitly.

OWL is not the right tool for the job, if you wish to validate graphs ‒ [SHACL](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/) is better.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here:

(1) I think how you specified the restriction is incorrect (or at least it is not read correctly by Protege - maybe a different ontology editor can make sense of this). The correct way to specify it is:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.ease-crc.org/ont/SOMA.owl#Hand">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#isRegionFor"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://example.org/test.owl#Span"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#isRegionFor"/>
            <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:maxCardinality>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</rdf:Description>
```

(2) Due to the open world assumption, an OWL reasoner will only make inferences based on explicitly stated information or other inferences - not on the absence of information. Absence of information is assumed to be merely be unknown rather than to not exist.  Thus, in your test it will not give an inconsistency because it is merely unknown whether your `Hand` instance is related to an instance of `Span` via `isRegionFor`. To test this, you need to make explicit that your hand instance does not have any relations via `isRegionFor`. I.e

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://example.org/test.owl#hand">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.ease-crc.org/ont/SOMA.owl#Hand"/>
    <rdf:type>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#isRegionFor"/>
            <owl:maxCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">0</owl:maxCardinality>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdf:type>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

With this test the reasoner will now complain.

(3) Namespaces are not the issue here at all. In reasoning namespaces will only be an issue if you use the same class/property name in different namespaces which have different axioms. From a reasoning perspective these
classes/properties are in fact different (except when equivalence of the class/property is explicitly stated).

(4) `owl:allValuesFrom` may not the appropriate restriction to be used here. Assuming you want also state that your hand instance is related via `isRegionFor` to an instance of `Arm`, where `Arm` is disjoint with `Span`, it will result in an inconsistency. This is because `owl:allValuesFrom` force individuals only to be of type `Hand`. To cater for the possibility for a hand to be linked to an `Arm` or `Span` you may want to change your `Hand` definition to:

```
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.ease-crc.org/ont/SOMA.owl#Hand">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#isRegionFor"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://example.org/test.owl#Span"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </rdf:Description>
```